# ffmpeg Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ffmpeg

My workstation seems to have plenty of memory (and everything). When I am trying to run ffmpeg as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg \
    -loglevel debug \
    -i "A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mov" \
    -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:2] amerge, aformat=sample_fmts=s16:channel_layouts=stereo [a]" \
    -map "[a]" \
    -map 0:5 \
    -c:a libfdk_aac \
    -vbr 3 \
    -vcodec libx264 \
    -profile:v baseline \
    -level 3.0 \
    -vf scale=1280:720 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -crf 20 \
    -metadata title="Test movie" \
    -movflags +faststart \
    -y \
    "A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mp4"
```

It fails with "Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory".

```
ffmpeg version N-86721-gf605b56-am Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
      configuration: --extra-version=am --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libsoxr --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-shared
      libavutil      55. 67.100 / 55. 67.100
      libavcodec     57.100.103 / 57.100.103
      libavformat    57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
      libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
      libavfilter     6. 94.100 /  6. 94.100
      libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
      libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
      libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
    Splitting the commandline.
    Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
    Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mov'.
    Reading option '-filter_complex' ... matched as option 'filter_complex' (create a complex filtergraph) with argument '[0:0] [0:2] amerge, aformat=sample_fmts=s16:channel_layouts=stereo [a]'.
    Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '[a]'.
    Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0:5'.
    Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libfdk_aac'.
    Reading option '-vbr' ... matched as AVOption 'vbr' with argument '3'.
    Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'libx264'.
    Reading option '-profile:v' ... matched as option 'profile' (set profile) with argument 'baseline'.
    Reading option '-level' ... matched as AVOption 'level' with argument '3.0'.
    Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'scale=1280:720'.
    Reading option '-pix_fmt' ... matched as option 'pix_fmt' (set pixel format) with argument 'yuv420p'.
    Reading option '-crf' ... matched as AVOption 'crf' with argument '20'.
    Reading option '-metadata' ... matched as option 'metadata' (add metadata) with argument 'title=Test movie'.
    Reading option '-movflags' ... matched as AVOption 'movflags' with argument '+faststart'.
    Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
    Reading option 'A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mp4' ... matched as output url.
    Finished splitting the commandline.
    Parsing a group of options: global .
    Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
    Applying option filter_complex (create a complex filtergraph) with argument [0:0] [0:2] amerge, aformat=sample_fmts=s16:channel_layouts=stereo [a].
    Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Parsing a group of options: input url A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mov.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an input file: A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mov.
    [NULL @ 0x1c4f920] Opening 'A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mov' for reading
    [file @ 0x1c4ffc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 129254400
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Processing st: 1, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 129254400
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Processing st: 2, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 129254400
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Processing st: 3, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 129254400
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Processing st: 4, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 1
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Processing st: 5, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 67320
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 59339926200 bytes read:760258 seeks:3 nb_streams:6
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] All info found
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1c4f920] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 1180516 bytes read:1945622 seeks:4 frames:144
    Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
    Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
    Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
    Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mov':
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2017-06-19T10:12:13.000000Z
        com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2017-06-19T13:12:13+0300
        com.apple.proapps.manufacturer: CANON
        com.apple.quicktime.make: CANON
        com.apple.proapps.mio.cameraName: EOS C300 Mark II
        com.apple.proapps.cameraname: EOS C300 Mark II
        com.apple.quicktime.model: EOS C300 Mark II
        com.apple.quicktime.camera.identifier: 060e2b34-0401-010d-0e15-0056454f0200
        com.divergentmedia.editready.timecodeStart: 05:45:28:08
        com.divergentmedia.editready.sonyXDCamTC: 05:45:28:08
        com.divergentmedia.editReady.version: EditReady 1.4.9, 798
        com.apple.proapps.studio.metadataFieldDominanceOverride: 1
        date            : 2017-06-19T13:12:13+0300
        date-eng        : 2017-06-19T13:12:13+0300
        make            : CANON
        make-eng        : CANON
        model           : EOS C300 Mark II
        model-eng       : EOS C300 Mark II
        timecode        : 05:45:28:08
      Duration: 00:44:52.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 176292 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng), 47, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-06-19T10:12:13.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
        Stream #0:1(eng), 47, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-06-19T10:12:13.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
        Stream #0:2(eng), 47, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-06-19T10:12:13.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
        Stream #0:3(eng), 1, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-06-19T10:12:13.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
        Stream #0:4(eng), 1, 1/25: Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0/1, 0 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-06-19T10:12:13.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          timecode        : 05:45:28:08
        Stream #0:5(eng), 1, 1/25: Video: prores, 1 reference frame (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 0/1, 173217 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-06-21T11:52:58.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
    Successfully opened the file.
    detected 16 logical cores
    [Parsed_aformat_1 @ 0x1c71a60] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
    [Parsed_aformat_1 @ 0x1c71a60] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value 'stereo'
    Parsing a group of options: output url A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mp4.
    Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument [a].
    Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0:5.
    Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument libfdk_aac.
    Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument libx264.
    Applying option profile:v (set profile) with argument baseline.
    Applying option vf (set video filters) with argument scale=1280:720.
    Applying option pix_fmt (set pixel format) with argument yuv420p.
    Applying option metadata (add metadata) with argument title=Test movie.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an output file: A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mp4.
    [file @ 0x1d4fe40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
    Successfully opened the file.
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le) -> amerge:in0 (graph 0)
      Stream #0:2 (pcm_s16le) -> amerge:in1 (graph 0)
      aformat (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libfdk_aac)
      Stream #0:5 -> #0:1 (prores (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
        Last message repeated 1 times
    [Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x2397e60] Setting 'w' to value '1280'
    [Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x2397e60] Setting 'h' to value '720'
    [Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x2397e60] Setting 'flags' to value 'bicubic'
    [Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x2397e60] w:1280 h:720 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:5 @ 0x23984c0] Setting 'video_size' to value '1920x1080'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:5 @ 0x23984c0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '74'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:5 @ 0x23984c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/25'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:5 @ 0x23984c0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:5 @ 0x23984c0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:5 @ 0x23984c0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '25/1'
    [graph 1 input from stream 0:5 @ 0x23984c0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv422p10le tb:1/25 fr:25/1 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
    [format @ 0x2399240] compat: called with args=[yuv420p]
    [format @ 0x2399240] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p'
    [AVFilterGraph @ 0x1d517e0] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
    [Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x2397e60] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv422p10le sar:1/1 -> w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 flags:0x4
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] using mv_range_thread = 24
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] using SAR=1/1
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame MB size (80x45) > level limit (1620)
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] MB rate (90000) > level limit (40500)
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=22 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
        Last message repeated 94 times
    [Parsed_aformat_1 @ 0x2559500] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
    [Parsed_aformat_1 @ 0x2559500] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value 'stereo'
    [graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x257c7c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
    [graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x257c7c0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
    [graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x257c7c0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's16'
    [graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x257c7c0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x4'
    [graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x257c7c0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x4
    [graph_0_in_0_2 @ 0x25820a0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
    [graph_0_in_0_2 @ 0x25820a0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
    [graph_0_in_0_2 @ 0x25820a0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's16'
    [graph_0_in_0_2 @ 0x25820a0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x4'
    [graph_0_in_0_2 @ 0x25820a0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x4
    [format_out_0_0 @ 0x2580ce0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
    [format_out_0_0 @ 0x2580ce0] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000'
    [format_out_0_0 @ 0x2580ce0] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value '0x4|0x3|0x7|0x107|0x37|0x3f|0xff|0x63f'
    [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x1c6edc0] No channel layout for input 1
    [AVFilterGraph @ 0x1c8abc0] query_formats: 5 queried, 6 merged, 0 already done, 9 delayed
    [AVFilterGraph @ 0x1c8abc0] query_formats not finished
    [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x1c6edc0] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
    [AVFilterGraph @ 0x1c8abc0] query_formats: 1 queried, 9 merged, 6 already done, 0 delayed
    [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x1c6edc0] in0:mono + in1:mono -> out:stereo
    [libfdk_aac @ 0x1d4e300] Note, the VBR setting is unsupported and only works with some parameter combinations
    Output #0, mp4, to 'A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mp4':
      Metadata:
        timecode        : 05:45:28:08
        com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2017-06-19T13:12:13+0300
        com.apple.proapps.manufacturer: CANON
        com.apple.quicktime.make: CANON
        com.apple.proapps.mio.cameraName: EOS C300 Mark II
        com.apple.proapps.cameraname: EOS C300 Mark II
        com.apple.quicktime.model: EOS C300 Mark II
        com.apple.quicktime.camera.identifier: 060e2b34-0401-010d-0e15-0056454f0200
        com.divergentmedia.editready.timecodeStart: 05:45:28:08
        com.divergentmedia.editready.sonyXDCamTC: 05:45:28:08
        com.divergentmedia.editReady.version: EditReady 1.4.9, 798
        com.apple.proapps.studio.metadataFieldDominanceOverride: 1
        date            : 2017-06-19T13:12:13+0300
        date-eng        : 2017-06-19T13:12:13+0300
        make            : CANON
        make-eng        : CANON
        model           : EOS C300 Mark II
        model-eng       : EOS C300 Mark II
        title           : Test movie
        encoder         : Lavf57.75.100
        Stream #0:0, 0, 1/48000: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, delay 2048 (default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.100.103 libfdk_aac
        Stream #0:1(eng), 0, 1/12800: Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2017-06-21T11:52:58.000000Z
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          encoder         : Lavc57.100.103 libx264
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
        Last message repeated 2 times
    Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
    cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
        Last message repeated 201 times
    cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream) 0x    
        Last message repeated 157 times
    cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream) 0x    
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   0 QP=19.02 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:3600 P:0    SKIP:0    size=49899 bytes
    Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   1 QP=19.20 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2   I:14   P:2118 SKIP:1468 size=6808 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   2 QP=18.86 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:4   I:15   P:2339 SKIP:1246 size=7088 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   3 QP=19.08 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:6   I:9    P:2449 SKIP:1142 size=7341 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   4 QP=18.92 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:8   I:5    P:2482 SKIP:1113 size=7725 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   5 QP=18.73 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:10  I:6    P:2100 SKIP:1494 size=6831 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   6 QP=18.73 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:12  I:4    P:2492 SKIP:1104 size=8298 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   7 QP=18.52 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:14  I:1    P:2397 SKIP:1202 size=7250 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   8 QP=18.51 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:16  I:7    P:1523 SKIP:2070 size=5344 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=   9 QP=18.51 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:18  I:6    P:2398 SKIP:1196 size=7865 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  10 QP=18.58 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:20  I:1    P:1840 SKIP:1759 size=6451 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  11 QP=18.58 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:22  I:5    P:1764 SKIP:1831 size=6159 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  12 QP=18.52 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:24  I:3    P:2421 SKIP:1176 size=8151 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  13 QP=18.51 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:26  I:1    P:1892 SKIP:1707 size=6476 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  14 QP=18.41 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:28  I:3    P:1919 SKIP:1678 size=6431 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  15 QP=18.48 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:30  I:1    P:1255 SKIP:2344 size=4060 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  16 QP=18.79 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:32  I:2    P:1373 SKIP:2225 size=4398 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  17 QP=18.77 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:34  I:2    P:1459 SKIP:2139 size=4480 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  18 QP=19.01 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:36  I:7    P:1658 SKIP:1935 size=5003 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] scene cut at 48 Icost:227110 Pcost:199261 ratio:0.1226 bias:0.1307 gop:48 (imb:3134 pmb:220)
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  19 QP=18.95 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:38  I:0    P:2461 SKIP:1139 size=7169 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  20 QP=19.01 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:40  I:1    P:2118 SKIP:1481 size=6048 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  21 QP=19.04 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:42  I:0    P:2114 SKIP:1486 size=5838 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  22 QP=18.97 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:44  I:3    P:2277 SKIP:1320 size=5952 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  23 QP=19.12 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:46  I:0    P:1658 SKIP:1942 size=4813 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  24 QP=19.33 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:48  I:0    P:1926 SKIP:1674 size=5503 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  25 QP=19.25 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:50  I:0    P:2470 SKIP:1130 size=6478 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  26 QP=19.21 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:52  I:0    P:2589 SKIP:1011 size=6985 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  27 QP=19.12 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:54  I:0    P:2312 SKIP:1288 size=6381 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  28 QP=19.20 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:56  I:2    P:2532 SKIP:1066 size=7296 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  29 QP=19.01 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:58  I:0    P:2611 SKIP:989  size=8186 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  30 QP=18.95 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:60  I:0    P:2582 SKIP:1018 size=7610 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  31 QP=19.02 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:62  I:2    P:2620 SKIP:978  size=8077 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  32 QP=19.09 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:64  I:1    P:1989 SKIP:1610 size=6214 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  33 QP=19.09 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:66  I:0    P:2483 SKIP:1117 size=7027 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  34 QP=19.17 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:68  I:0    P:2477 SKIP:1123 size=6833 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  35 QP=19.07 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:70  I:1    P:2373 SKIP:1226 size=6915 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  36 QP=19.28 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:72  I:3    P:2400 SKIP:1197 size=6975 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  37 QP=19.21 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:74  I:1    P:2643 SKIP:956  size=7505 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  38 QP=19.40 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:76  I:0    P:2289 SKIP:1311 size=6682 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  39 QP=19.52 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:78  I:1    P:2074 SKIP:1525 size=5823 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  40 QP=19.72 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:80  I:2    P:2420 SKIP:1178 size=6552 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  41 QP=19.99 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:82  I:274  P:2019 SKIP:1307 size=7398 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  42 QP=19.77 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:84  I:545  P:1946 SKIP:1109 size=7933 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  43 QP=19.52 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:86  I:523  P:1969 SKIP:1108 size=7596 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  44 QP=19.25 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:88  I:649  P:1303 SKIP:1648 size=6070 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  45 QP=18.80 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:90  I:949  P:1115 SKIP:1536 size=6608 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  46 QP=18.51 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:92  I:915  P:1141 SKIP:1544 size=6499 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  47 QP=18.38 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:94  I:882  P:1071 SKIP:1647 size=6326 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  48 QP=15.38 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:3600 P:0    SKIP:0    size=15254 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  49 QP=18.47 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2   I:870  P:1178 SKIP:1552 size=9327 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  50 QP=18.35 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:4   I:691  P:1606 SKIP:1303 size=9056 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  51 QP=18.56 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:6   I:567  P:1697 SKIP:1336 size=9923 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  52 QP=18.72 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:8   I:500  P:1725 SKIP:1375 size=10632 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  53 QP=18.46 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:10  I:537  P:1789 SKIP:1274 size=9973 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  54 QP=18.55 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:12  I:478  P:1916 SKIP:1206 size=10196 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  55 QP=18.68 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:14  I:446  P:2027 SKIP:1127 size=10172 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  56 QP=19.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:16  I:284  P:2138 SKIP:1178 size=9705 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  57 QP=19.10 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:18  I:244  P:2116 SKIP:1240 size=9518 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  58 QP=19.39 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:20  I:239  P:2231 SKIP:1130 size=8953 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  59 QP=19.16 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:22  I:178  P:2379 SKIP:1043 size=9059 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  60 QP=19.28 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:24  I:58   P:2329 SKIP:1213 size=8257 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  61 QP=19.21 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:26  I:34   P:2231 SKIP:1335 size=6689 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  62 QP=19.55 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:28  I:14   P:2219 SKIP:1367 size=6164 bytes
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame=  63 QP=20.04 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:30  I:8    P:1836 SKIP:1756 size=4318 bytes
    [mp4 @ 0x1d4c880] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
    [mp4 @ 0x1d4c880] Opening 'A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mp4' for reading
    [file @ 0xa01a460] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
    [AVIOContext @ 0x6b95260] Statistics: 509968 bytes read, 0 seeks
    frame=   64 fps= 48 q=-1.0 Lsize=     500kB time=00:00:02.52 bitrate=1625.5kbits/s speed=1.88x    
    video:497kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.417128%
    Input file #0 (A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mov):
      Input stream #0:0 (audio): 141 packets read (288000 bytes); 141 frames decoded (144000 samples); 
      Input stream #0:1 (audio): 47 packets read (96000 bytes); 
      Input stream #0:2 (audio): 141 packets read (288000 bytes); 141 frames decoded (144000 samples); 
      Input stream #0:3 (audio): 1 packets read (2048 bytes); 
      Input stream #0:4 (data): 1 packets read (4 bytes); 
      Input stream #0:5 (video): 64 packets read (59520416 bytes); 64 frames decoded; 
      Total: 395 packets (60194468 bytes) demuxed
    Output file #0 (A066C002_170619NU_CANON.mp4):
      Output stream #0:0 (audio): 1 frames encoded (1024 samples); 3 packets muxed (740 bytes); 
      Output stream #0:1 (video): 64 frames encoded; 64 packets muxed (509175 bytes); 
      Total: 67 packets (509915 bytes) muxed
    346 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
    [AVIOContext @ 0x1c71880] Statistics: 4 seeks, 7 writeouts
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame I:2     Avg QP:17.20  size: 32576
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] frame P:62    Avg QP:18.99  size:  7152
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] mb I  I16..4: 49.2%  0.0% 50.8%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] mb P  I16..4:  3.5%  0.0%  1.0%  P16..4: 45.1%  8.4%  3.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:38.5%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 30.7% 30.5% 4.8% inter: 7.0% 19.1% 0.3%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 47% 21%  9% 23%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 18% 18%  5%  6%  4%  5%  4%  3%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 72% 11% 15%  2%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] ref P L0: 63.8% 36.2%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d4f1a0] kb/s:1589.21
    [AVIOContext @ 0x1c583a0] Statistics: 61656934 bytes read, 59 seeks
```

I happen to be absolute beginner (at least in ffmpeg). What went wrong?

Thanks! Andres Mere

Comment: I have the same issue: Converting from H264 to H265 cause my workstation to fill about 24GB of RAM, so that it's hanging. After a while, I got "ffmpeg didn't respond", and the same `Cannot allocate memory` exception. Working on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Same. Amerge filter eats all the memory.