# ffmpeg amerge Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

This seems to be a recurring problem, as seen here: [ffmpeg Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971775/ffmpeg-error-while-filtering-cannot-allocate-memory) . I ask this only because that question has no answer.

I get a memory error every time I try to use amerge to combine music and a video (with audio). I am at a loss as to how to get around this, so if there are any other command line alternatives that do the same thing (combining audio with video, merging the new audio and the current audio on the video) any suggestions would be much appreciated.

FYI, here is the ffprobe information for the two files I am trying to combine:

video (mp4):

```
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 21.104 / 58. 21.104
  libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:11:08.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1957 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1887 kb/s, 0.66 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 68 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

audio (mp3):

```
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 21.104 / 58. 21.104
  libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'song0.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:06:20.79, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64
```

EDIT:

Here is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i song0.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a libvorbis -ac 2 -shortest out.mp4
```

EDIT 2:

Added updated ffprobe with updated ffmpeg version

video:

```
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.105 / 58. 47.105
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:11:08.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1957 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1887 kb/s, 0.66 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 68 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Audio:

```
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.105 / 58. 47.105
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'song0.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:06:20.79, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64
```

I tried again with the updated version, still the exact same error.

Comment: Your build looks to be 8 months old. Upgrade and check. You can also switch to amix filter.

Comment: I updated - Error still occurs.

What is the amix filter? Where would I use that and why is that one better?

Comment: You would use it in place of amerge. It's more forgiving of differing inputs.

Comment: Thankyou, amix worked nicely. Used signficantly less ram as well.